# Call method only if it exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there some hidden Ruby/Rails-magic for simply calling a method only if it exists?

Lets say I want to call

```
resource.phone_number
```

but I don't know beforehand if resource responds to `phone_number`. A way to do this is

```
resource.phone_number if resource.respond_to? :phone_number
```

That's not all that pretty if used in the wrong place. I'm curious if something exists that works more along the lines of how `try` is used (`resource.try(:phone_number)`).

Comment: As an extreme example I would recommend overwriting `method_missing` of `Object`to return `nil` in this case. This is horror to debug. And some people would consider it bad style, meta and unnecessary.

Comment: @User bah, not a horrow at all. You are simply to rewing a stack back to where nil exception was thrown :-)

Comment: using `respond_to` is the best option

Comment: Feel free to add that as a separate answer and I'll give you an accept for it.

Comment: @Frans would you mind accepting the answer with most upvotes so I can delete my incorrect answer?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read my own question thoroughly enough when changing the accepted answer.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

If you are not satisfied with the standard ruby syntax for that, you are free to:

```
class Object
  def try_outside_rails(meth, *args, &cb)
    self.send(meth.to_sym, *args, &cb) if self.respond_to?(meth.to_sym)
  end
end
```

Now:

```
resource.try_outside_rails(:phone_number)
```

will behave as you wanted.

Comment: you're overriding the existing `try` method in Rails

Comment: Ruby can be fairly awesome. This isn't recurring enough for me to need to define a method of my own for it, I just wondered if it already existed a method for it.

Comment: @apneadiving Who talked about `Rails`?

Comment: the question is tagged [tag:ruby-on-rails]

Comment: I did. I tagged the question and mentioned the already existing method `try`. Just to be safe I submitted an edit to your answer, as it'd probably be bad practice to implement a `try` method that doesn't do the same thing as in Rails.

Comment: @Frans I would say that Ruby is smart enough to prevent you of shooting your own leg. The contract is: you are to say the Ruby what you actually want and Ruby is to perform it. Programmers after you, supporting your code, will ship you “thanks” if there is a clause like “`if ghgh.respond_to?`—” since it makes a code clearer.

Comment: @mudasobwa Absolutely true that it makes the code clearer, that's why I wouldn't implement it without a great need for it. But if an existing, prettier way would've existed already I would've wanted to know about it. :)

Comment: See also: https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/11537 -- new try-like syntax in ruby.

Comment: `respond_to?` only yields true when challenging for a public member, protected and private members will yield false, but they are still accessible via `instance.send(:method, args)`

Answer (score 18):

I would try `defined?` (http://ruby-doc.org/docs/keywords/1.9/Object.html#defined-3F-method). It seems to do exactly what you are asking for:

```
resource.phone_number if defined? resource.phone_number
```

Comment: This does not work as `resource.phone_number` is a valid expression. It will always return true if `resource` is in scope.

Answer (score 13):

I know this is very old post. But just wanted to know if this could be a possible answer and whether the impact is the same .

```
resource.try(:phone_number) rescue nil
```

Thanks

Comment: With Rails 4 you don't even need the `rescue`: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-try

Comment: The 'try' method isn't about checking if a method exists, it's about protecting you from a nil. E.g. `nil.try(:some_method)` will return `nil` instead of raising an exception, but `valid_reference.try(:non_existant_method)` will still fail (unless, as you've done, you add `rescue nil`).

Comment: It's not a good practice to use rescue in the normal flow of a program.  Throwing and catching exceptions adds overhead to the program.

Comment: @Josh I don't think the overhead is the main issue; using Ruby in the first question already adds a magnitude of overhead. But, it distorts the control flow, making the program harder to understand. Exceptions should be used for exceptional cases, not standard control flow. So, you were right but I think you were using the wrong argument. :)

Comment: This is awful and you shouldn't do it. If any exception occurs in the called method (even a syntax error), it will be caught and ignored.

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak for the efficiency, but something like...

```
Klass.methods.include?(:method_name)
```

works for me in Rails 4

Comment: This should work in most cases (though `Klass.method_defined?` is more direct). A potential problem is, though, any method can be disabled specifically for a chosen instance (with [`Module#undef_method`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-undef_method) as a singleton class). So, chances are your method does not work. [This past answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44107544/respond-to-versus-defined/58673436#58673436) summarises what would be best depending on the exact demand.

Answer (score -2):

If `A.c` is defined and `A.a` and `A.b` are not, you can do `A.a rescue A.b rescue A.c` and it will work like a charm. You will be breaking some silly rules, though.